# separar elementos de un array con la misma clave

Tags: php

buenas tardes actualmente tengo lo siguiente

```
          ["id"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> string(3) "6,1" 
          }
```

no se que tipo de array es y deseo obtener sus claves para almacenar e iterar en un ciclo for, como hago para separar ese string y que me quede asi

```
      ["id"]=> array(1) { 
                     [0]=> string(1) "6"
                     [1]=> string(1) "1" 
      }
```

trate haciendo lo siguiente

```
       $data['id'] = explode(',',$data['id'] );
```

Comment: Los datos que nos muestras están en el índice `0`, de modo que el `explode` debería ser así para este caso: `explode(',',$data['id'][0]);` de todos modos la pregunta es un poco vaga, no se sabe si puede haber más elementos, no se entiende lo que quieres hacer. Es más, quizá haya formas más simples de lograr un determinado objetivo, pero si no explicas nada, poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Estas trabajando con Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con la poca información que nos dispones, supondré dos casos, el primero donde tu variable $id, solo contiene un registro y el otro donde tienes un array de arrays.

**Caso uno:**

```
  $id = [
            ["6,1"],
    ];
```

Obtienes el dato solicitado de la siguiente forma:

```
$caso1 = explode(",", $id[0][0]);
var_dump($caso1);
```

var_dump obtenido:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

**Caso 2 (Array de Arrays):**

```
$id = [
        ["6,1"],
        ["6,2"],
        ["6,3"],
];
```

Obtienes el dato solicitado de la siguiente forma:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach ($id as $index => $item) {
    $caso2 = explode(",", $item[0]);
    array_push($new_array, $caso2);
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

var_dump obtenido:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Si de lo contrario y como extra, lo que quieres es obtener todos los datos separados por comas en un solo array simple, puedes obtenerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$id = [
        ["6,1"],
        ["6,2"],
        ["6,3"],
];


$new_array = [];
foreach ($id as $index => $item) {
    $caso2 = explode(",", $item[0]);
    foreach ($caso2 as $c){
        array_push($new_array, $c);
    }
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

var_dump obtenido:

```
 [0]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```